# How do I generate a ranking of columns in Google Sheets? Do I use ArrayFormula?

Tags: sql, google-sheets

Here's a picture as an example:

[image: sheet]

The left side is the raw data I currently have, consisting of columns of teams A, B, C, D, E, F. Each row represents 1 game, and many games are played (this spreadsheet has several thousand rows).

How do I generate a ranking of the teams, like what I manually did on the right side? I want to sort the teams by the number of points they have.

In the first row, Team A scores the most points, so they are ranked 1st; Team C scores the second most points, and thus are in the second column, etc.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to sort by column in each row, rather than sorting by column, which is what the default sort() function does. I've tried multiple methods, including using the google SQL query function, (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) but couldn't figure out how to use that either.

Is using ArrayFormula() a good idea in this situation? How would I implement that? This sheet does have several thousand rows, so it would be much better if I can just put an ArrayFormula() in the first row, rather than manually autofilling every row.

Answer (score 1):

You may use costum formula, for cell H2:

```
=ArraySort(A1:F1,A2:F2001)
```

here's the code to paste into script editor:

```
function ArraySort(Arr1, Arr2) {

  var w = Arr1[0].length;  
  var column = [];
  var row = []; 
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < Arr2.length; i++) {      
      row = [];      
      for (var k = 0; k < w; k++) {        
        column[k] = [Arr2[i][k],Arr1[0][k]];
      }       
      column.sort(sortFunction);
      for (var j = 0; j < w; j++) {        
        row[j] = column[j][1];
      }      
      result.push(row);
  }

return result;

}


function sortFunction(a, b) {
    if (a[0] === b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[0] > b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following formula creates the ranking in the second row:

```
=array_constrain(transpose(sort(transpose({A$1:F$1; A2:F2}), 2, False)), 1, 6)
```

It can be copied down to rank the rest of rows. I do not think there is an arrayformula approach that would sort an array of arrays.

Explanation of the formula: it creates a two-row array (team names and scores), transposes it so the scores become the second column, sorts by that column, transposes again, and keeps only the names (the first row).